# C browser displays server socket response on webpage, but webpage keeps loading

Tags: c, sockets

I am new to learning C sockets, and I was able to successfully send an html `<h1>hello world!</h1>` as `text/html` content from a C socket server to the browser(client). However, even though the `h1` tag displays correctly, I'm not sure why the page is stuck with a loading indicator. I tried adding a  `Content-Length` property to indicate the length of my response, which works, but I was told that this shouldn't be necessary.

I think I am reading and writing properly to the socket, so I'm not sure what's hanging. Code:

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

void servConn(int port)
{

  int sd, new_sd;
  struct sockaddr_in name, cli_name;
  int sock_opt_val = 1;
  int cli_len;
  char data[256]; /* Our receive data buffer. */

  if ((sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
  {
    perror("(servConn): socket() error");
    exit(-1);
  }

  if (setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&sock_opt_val, sizeof(sock_opt_val)) < 0)
  {
    perror("(servConn): Failed to set SO_REUSEADDR on INET socket");
    exit(-1);
  }

  name.sin_family = AF_INET;
  name.sin_port = htons(port);
  name.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

  if (bind(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&name, sizeof(name)) < 0)
  {
    perror("(servConn): bind() error");
    exit(-1);
  }

  listen(sd, 5);

  for (;;)
  {
    cli_len = sizeof(cli_name);
    new_sd = accept(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_name, &cli_len);
    printf("Assigning new socket descriptor:  %d\n", new_sd);

    if (new_sd < 0)
    {
      perror("(servConn): accept() error");
      exit(-1);
    }

    if (fork() == 0)
    { /* Child process. */
      close(sd);
      char reply[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/html\n\n";
      char *requestType;
      char *filename;
      int status = 200;
      char *strPter;
      int index = 0;
      char c;
      while (1)
      {
        read(new_sd, &c, 1);
        if (index > 254)
        {
          data[index] = '\0';
          break;
        }

        if (c == '\n')
        {
          data[index] = '\0';
          break;
        }
        else
        {
          data[index++] = c;
        }
      }
      printf("read: %d bytes: %s\n", index, data);

      requestType = strtok_r(data, " ", &strPter);
      if (strcmp(requestType, "GET") != 0)
        status = 501;
      else
        printf("request was GET\n");

      filename = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &strPter);
      printf("filename: %s\n", filename);
      strtok_r(NULL, " ", &strPter);

      char *response = "<h1>hello world!</h1>";
      strcat(reply, response);

      printf("\nresponse is (%d): \n%s\n\n", strlen(reply), reply);
      send(new_sd, reply, strlen(reply), 0);

      close(new_sd);
      printf("closed connection!\n");
      exit(0);
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  servConn(5050); /* Server port. */
  return 0;
}
```

Here is my output, which seems to be in the correct HTTP format:
[image]

Here is the browser output, which is stuck in loading even though the content is displayed:
[image]

How do I correctly close the socket and stop the page from loading after sending hello world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before calling

```
close(new_sd);
```

you need

```
shutdown(new_sd, SHUT_RDWR);
```

It is this call that sends proper connection termination sequence. `close` doesn't, it just destroys the socket.